# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum - Failed to encode image for saved photos

Tags: ios, uiimage

In my main ViewController, I generate an image from `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`. The image is assigned to a UIImage, and I've tested it by placing in a UIImageView in the main view, so I can see it. Works just fine. However when I tap a button I've assigned to save it, I get the error: `-3304 "Failed to encode image for saved photos."`

screenshot code:

```
 CGSize mySize = CGSizeMake(530, 350);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mySize);
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -444, -313);
 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 // self.screenshot is a UIImage declared in .h
 self.screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Save code:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, self, @selector(imageWasSavedSuccessfully:didSaveWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
```

Not sure if I'm not meeting the requirements for camera roll images, or if that method can only be used in conjunction with the UIPickerController class. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you opened the photos app on your device before? Is self.screenshot nil? (Are you sure that your screenshot variable is the same as self.screenshot?)

Comment: @JesseRusak You're right... the screenshot var is nil. I have a popover to determine whether the user wants to save it or upload it, and since the popover uses a separate view controller for its content, which holds the save action, I need to make sure I'm passing the var properly... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the issue was that the image to be saved was nil.

Answer (score -1):

Try to save your image like this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil);
```

or maybe

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.screenshot, nil, nil, nil);
```

or maybe even

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, self, nil, nil);
```